# regression model

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis

> Regression models:
>   \begin{align}
> Y_{i1} &= \alpha + \beta X_{i1} + \varepsilon_i \\
> Y_{i2} &= \alpha + \beta X_{i2} + \eta_i
> \end{align}
>   for $i = 1, 2, \ldots , n.$ In other words the observation come in pairs. Assume
>   that $E(\varepsilon_i) = E(\eta_i) = 0$, $V(\varepsilon_i) = V(\eta_i) = \sigma^2$, and $cor(\varepsilon_i, \eta_i) = \rho \in (−1, 1)$. Assume that the pairs, $(\varepsilon_1, \eta_1), \dots ,(\varepsilon_n, \eta_n)$, are uncorrelated. Furthermore, assume that $\sum(x_{i1}x_{i2}) = 0$.
>
> a. Assume that $\rho$ is known. Find the best linear unbiased estimate of the
>   regression parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Find an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$.
>
> b. Assume that $\rho$ is unknown and let $\hat \alpha$ and $\hat \beta$ be the ordinary least squares estimators of the regression parameters. Compute the standard errors of the two estimators.
>
> c. Give an estimate of $V(\hat \alpha)$ and $V(\hat \beta)$. Are the estimators unbiased?

Should I start by using a matrix method?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Please provide an informative title and consider adding `self-study` tag.

Comment: Do also read [our policy on self-study questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) - can you tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck?

Comment: we can start by first taking the E(Yi1 and Yi2) which will put both error terms (e, n ) to zero and thus by calculating similar way for V(e and n ) which is variance .                                                             
 then sigma^2 = (xi1-x)^2 and similar for xi2....now i am confused weather to combine both the equation and solve or to do it independently ?